# Async loading images in WPF value converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF listbox, which will bind a lot of images. Each image may will from local disk or get icon from Exe itself.

I put all those parse codes in MultiValueConverter. But it now seems block the UI. How to make that async?

Code Sample: https://github.com/qianlifeng/Wox/blob/master/Wox/Converters/ImagePathConverter.cs#L53

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your code here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can leverage `IsAsync` property of `Binding`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync):

> Use the IsAsync property when the get accessor of your binding source
>   property might take a long time. One example is an image property with
>   a get accessor that downloads from the Web. Setting IsAsync to true
>   avoids blocking the UI while the download occurs.

example

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImage,IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

more on [Binding.IsAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync)

---

**Async Converter**

I managed to create a async converter

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class AsyncConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new AsyncTask(() =>
             {
                 Thread.Sleep(4000); //long running job eg. download image.
                 return "success";
             });
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public class AsyncTask : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public AsyncTask(Func<object> valueFunc)
            {
                AsyncValue = "loading async value"; //temp value for demo
                LoadValue(valueFunc);  
            }

            private async Task LoadValue(Func<object> valueFunc)
            {
                AsyncValue =  await Task<object>.Run(()=> 
                    {
                        return valueFunc();
                    });
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AsyncValue"));
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public object AsyncValue { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

this converter will return an instance of `AsyncTask` which will encapsulate the long running job within

class `AsyncTask` will execute the task asynchronously and will set the result to  `AsyncValue` as it also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` hence using the notification to update the UI

usage

```
<Grid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <l:AsyncConverter x:Key="AsyncConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding MyProperty,Converter={StaticResource AsyncConverter}}"
               Text="{Binding AsyncValue}" />
</Grid>
```

Idea is to bind the `DataContext` of the element to the converter and the desired property to the AsyncValue of the new data context

above example is using Text property of a text block for easy demo

exmaple is made for a `IValueConverter` same approach can be used for `IMultiValueConverter` too.

Comment: This will only call the MyImage getter asynchronously, not the converter (which was what OP asked for). And please mark citations from other resources (e.g. *From MSDN*: `Use the IsAsync property ...`).

Comment: I got the point. As a workaround a calculate property can be used to execute the long running function instead of converter. I am trying to find a way to use converters async.

Comment: A possible workaround would be another view model property, that you could bind asynchronously *without* a converter.

Comment: @pushpraj check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2463852/468718) where user is loading image from web but then also it hangs the application because some operation is still executing on main thread so `IsAsync` is not good idea.

Comment: @Clemens I'm going to do that if other ways won't work.

Comment: Hi @Clemens did you see the updated approach? Do you find it feasible?

Comment: Hi I tried to use the given code but it only works for `TextBlock` Control when returning `string` from converter however same code for `Image` Control returning `BitmapImage` from converter it fails to update the image and gives error `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll` in VS output window.

Comment: ok when I return string path of image it starts working.. not sure why returning `BitmapImage` is not working..

Comment: I guess an image source should be returned, the approach is just an async wrapper, it has nothing to do with the value. By default it should work with any type.

Comment: @Harsh Baid That error is due to the fact that you bound the DataContext, not the property, and the DataContext uses the converter. The thing is, here the converter isn't actually a "converter", it's more like a trick to set and raise a property after a task. 
Try replacing 'return "success"' with 'return value'

Answer (score -2):

First you should provide some sample code so it easy to reproduce for answerers.

**`IsAsync` will not help**

Using `IsAsync` binding will not help because of below reasons:

1. I have observed that when loading images dynamically with IsAsync it will lead to memory leaks at times. So avoid this sugar candy `IsAsync` property
2. `IsAsync` will not always help as one problem case mentioned in the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2463852/468718) where OP is trying to load image from web but wpf is resolving DNS on main thread so again application hangs for while

**Solution is Use Attached Binding Property in WPF**

Details:

1. You should put some thumbnail image on `Source` in XAML
2. Write one Attached Property class to load the image in background and Update Image Source in when its available (sample code below for similar kind of use case)

```
<Image my:ImageAsyncHelper.SourceUri="{Binding Author.IconUrl}" />
```

**Attached Property class**

```
public class ImageAsyncHelper : DependencyObject
{
  public static Uri GetSourceUri(DependencyObject obj) { return (Uri)obj.GetValue(SourceUriProperty); }
  public static void SetSourceUri(DependencyObject obj, Uri value) { obj.SetValue(SourceUriProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceUriProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SourceUri", typeof(Uri), typeof(ImageAsyncHelper), new PropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
    {
      ((Image)obj).SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
        new Binding("VerifiedUri")
        {
          Source = new ImageAsyncHelper { GivenUri = (Uri)e.NewValue },
          IsAsync = true,
        });
    }
  });

  Uri GivenUri;
  public Uri VerifiedUri
  {
    get
    {
      try
      {
        Dns.GetHostEntry(GivenUri.DnsSafeHost);
        return GivenUri;
      }
      catch(Exception)
      {
        return null;
      }

    } 
  } 
}
```

And if you need to use `IMultiValueConverter` with attached property defined above then it should go like below xaml code:

**Attached Property with `IMultiValueConverter`**

```
<Image>
    <my:ImageAsyncHelper.SourceUri>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyImageMultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding Source="Author" Path="IconUrl"/> <!-- Binding Parameters -->
            <Binding Path="ImageType"/> <!-- Binding Parameters -->
            <Binding Path="MyParameterToConverter"/> <!-- Binding Parameters -->
        </MultiBinding>
    </my:ImageAsyncHelper.SourceUri>
</Image>
```

**Reference links**

1. [How can I keep a WPF Image from blocking if the ImageSource references an unreachable Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467510/468718)
2. [Using multibinding to set custom attached property in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12960097/468718)

Comment: This solution seems to depend entirely on `IsAsync` (in the `new Binding()` code), despite your warnings not to use it.