# Detecting when PropertyChangedEventHandler changes

Tags: c#, wpf

My PropertyChanged event is getting set properly when I watch the variable, but somewhere in code it gets reset to null and I have no idea how to figure out where this is happening.

Here is come code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  //this is in the NotifyTaskCompletion class, as used from the blog 
 // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx
  private async Task WatchTaskAsync(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task; //After this task, PropertyChanged gets set to a non-null method("Void OnPropertyChanged()")
        }
        catch
        {
        }
      //PropertyChanged, which was set to a value after the task was run, and still not null  during IdentifyCompleted getting set, is now null here
       var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged; 
        if (propertyChanged == null)
            return;
        //other code
}


  //My Watch variable of PropertyChanged is still good after this setter is run.
  public NotifyTaskCompletion<GraphicCollection> IdentifyCompleted
     {
         get { return _IdentifyCompleted; }
         set
         {
             _IdentifyCompleted = value;
         //    _IdentifyCompleted.PropertyChanged+= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(this, new     PropertyChangedEventArgs("IdentifyCompleted")); 
            // NotifyPropertyChanged();
         }
     }
```

My main issue is that I cannot use a {set;get;} on PropertyChanged to attempt to identify WHERE it is getting set to null. So my main question, unless anyone sees something that is obviously wrong, is how would I go about finding out where it is getting set to null? Thank you for any assistance.

**EDIT**

As per the last posters suggestion, I set my code as follows:

```
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { _propertyChanged += value; }
        remove { _propertyChanged -= value; }
    }
```

And here is the issue.

```
//this is in my View Model. The ViewModel CONTAINS NotifyTaskCompletion<GraphicCollection> IdentifyCompleted  which in turn implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has its own PropertyChanged that is not getting set

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
//This line sets the PopertyChanged in the view model AND in the NotifyTaskCompletion class somehow, but I don't know how it is setting it properly in the NotifyTaskCompletion class in my other project where this code works, When I step through this line in my code, it doesn't trigger
//the add{} of the PropertyChanged in NotifyTaskCompletion, but it DOES in my other project...
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

So with all that said, I can now see what line SHOULD be working, but I have no idea WHY it isn't working. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: show us the calling code for `WatchTaskAsync` method.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

I am using his exact code and was trying to mimic the way he did things to get things working. It works in one project, but not another.

Comment: it seems like you are trying to create async bindings. see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731335/async-loading-images-in-wpf-value-converter/24731602#24731602 can help you in this case.

Comment: You appear to be confusing raising an event with adding a handler.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to answer your question without seeing more of your code. On a side note your NotifyPropertyChanged method has a race condition: PropertyChanged could become null after the null test. I suggest you first store PropertyChanged in a local variable and then use only this local variable.

Comment: Use your debugger and set breakpoints when you remove your handler.

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own event accessors:

```
private PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged {
    add { propertyChanged += value; }
    remove { propertyChanged -= value; }
}
```

You can then set breakpoints.
Note that this is not thread-safe.

Comment: Should use `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove` for thread safety.

Comment: @Zer0: Wrong; `+=` and `-=` compile to to those methods, and both are equally vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: Whoops.  What I meant to say is he should use `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove` along with `Interlocked.CompareExchange` like .NET does when you do `+=` or `-=` on an event.  That way he can use this for debugging without introducing a race condition.

Comment: Context: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/08/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-ii-semantic-changes-and.aspx